How to delete file or folder in Ubuntu Disk?
I've encountered an issue while attempting to remove the Timeshift folder from my Ubuntu system. When I right-click on the folder, the usual 'delete' option is missing. I'm unable to proceed with the deletion process. Could you please provide some guidance on how to resolve this.
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS


perhaps [edit] your question to say what it actually is you are trying to achieve her. If it is to remove Timeshift from your system then this Ask Ubuntu Q&A will be more helpful

This is easy to solve in your terminal.  Just type:
sudo nautilus

This will bring up your file explorer with root permissions. Be careful!  You can now delete the file by navigating there with root Nautilus.  Close the file browser when done to stop using root.

Running sudo nautilus is not safe and is not good practice. pkexec nautilus is a safer option. Or better, open the admin:// path. Since the user will use the command line for a single action, it would be easier to use rm -rf /timeshift. If they keep Nautilus open in sudo mode, there's a higher risk of damaging their system if they aren't familiar with it.

And if they sneeze after typing    rm -rf  /    accidentally pressing Enter too soon, there is no danger?
